# Matrix inequalities question

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, inequality

Let $A, B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$.

Assume that:

$$ 0 \preccurlyeq 2 A^\top A \preccurlyeq A^\top + A $$

$$ B^\top + B \preccurlyeq 0 $$

Is the following inequality true?

$$  A B + B^\top A^\top \preccurlyeq 2 I $$

I think it is true if $A=A^\top$ and $B = B^\top$, but I am not able to generalize.

Comment: How is $\preccurlyeq $ defined?

Comment: $0 \preccurlyeq X$ means that $X = X^\top$ has non-negative eigenvalues. [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix]

Comment: And what does $A \preccurlyeq B$ mean for some $n\times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$??

Comment: It means that $0 \preccurlyeq B-A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality is implausible. If it's true, it would imply that $AB+B^\top A^\top$ is always negative semidefinite (otherwise the inequality will eventually be violated by scaling $B$ by a very large number). At any rate, here is a random counterexample:
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&0},
\ B = \pmatrix{0&3\\ -3&0}.
$$
We have $A^\top+A = 2A^\top A \succeq 0$ and $B+B^\top=0$. It is easy to verify that the eigenvalues of
$$
C := AB+B^\top A^\top = \pmatrix{0&3\\ 3&0}
$$
are $\pm3$. So, $C\not\preceq2I$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you think that under additional conditions on $B$, say $-2 I \preccurlyeq B + B^\top $ or so, the inequality may be true?

Comment: @Adam See my new edit. In this new counterexample, we also have $-2I\preceq B+B^\top=0$. So, your additional condition is not enough to guarantee the desired property. However, if $B$ is symmetric and $-I\preceq B=B^\top\preceq0$, one can prove that the operator 2-norms of both $A$ and $B$ are at most 1 and hence $AB+B^\top A^\top\preceq 2I$.